# Google Chrome Stable crashing after a min

Tags: google-chrome, google

I have been using google chrome on my Ubuntu 18.04.6 for a long time. However, yesterday, it suddenly started to close/crash after a min from opening the browser.
I do hear the computer fan sound increase just before it crushes.
Any help, please?

Comment: You may want to check your logs, such as `/var/log/syslog`. This may point to the reason for the crash.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, it says:
bash: /var/log/syslog: Permission denied

Comment: @jord you need root access.

Comment: it gives lots and lots of different and repeated errors about chrome